# How to eliminate double quote in JavaScript while reading variable from Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm trying to call a variable from my controller:

```
model.addAttribute("something",someService.getSomething()); /// output is a json string will be read by vue.js
```

and my js file embedded in the html

```
<script th:inline="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var something = [[${something}]];
  console.log(something);
</script>
```

The output of the console is exactly what I expected.
But when I check the page source, the output is double quoted.

```
var something = "MY OUTPUT";
```

How can I make it not generate the double quotes?

Comment: What exactly is the desired result?

Comment: i hope inside the js can be without the double quotations.
like 
var something = MY OUTPUT;

Comment: You can't remove the quotes from around a string in Javascript, otherwise it wouldn't be a string...

Comment: cuz our vue.js designer made it as a json-ish data... it will be read by vue.js; and the double quotes should not be there :(

Comment: Do you mean the actual string is `"MY OUTPUT"`? The string includes the `"` marks?

Comment: If so you can use regex `something.replace(/"/g, '')` this will find all occurences of the `"` and replace it with an empty string `''` which will 'remove' the `"`

Comment: the actual string is only MY OUTPUT, something like    {a:{json}, b:{json}, c:{json}};

Comment: but when it's in the js it will be double quoted "{a:{json}, b:{json}, c:{json}}";

Comment: problem solved!! thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved the problem by changing it into

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/

  var something = /*[(${something})]*/ '';

  /*]]>*/
  console.log(something);
</script>
```

[[${something}]] -> [(${something})];

Comment: Works for me! There's some documentation from thymeleaf or spring engine mechanism which explains this difference between [[]] and [()]??

Comment: yes it's unescaped: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining